# Where is the offical EOS Developer Documentation?

Tags: documentation

Where is the official developer documentation provided by EOS?

Comment: Why downvotes? This is a specific question, and good to be searchable by Google, and draw more devs to this beta. SEO yo

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The official papers can be found under their github on https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation.

The RPC and smart contract interface is here: https://developers.eos.io/

Answer (score 16):

Here are the main sources:

- [Developer Portal](https://developers.eos.io/): Primary source. Replaced the wiki and multiple github-hosted sites.
- [eosiolib headers for contracts](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.wasmsdk/tree/master/libraries/eosiolib): Part of eosio.wasmsdk.

Answer (score 5):

The question asks for official Documentation sources which has already been answered by lucca65

Although not an official source, it might be worth checking out https://www.eosdocs.io/

They are "an Open Source project which encourages the community to contribute to exceptional EOS documentation."  I feel this is important to mention as the spirit of EOS is very much about community and mutual contribution.  In my opinion the documentation there has already exceeded the official sources.

***EDIT 2018-06-20***

It appears that the official documentation listed above is now deprecated. According to EOSIO GitHub  `The wiki is deprecated and will be removed June 30th. Please check out the constantly improving developers portal`

The developers portal can be found here: https://developers.eos.io/